# Best way to render 3D polygons to an image buffer (rather than a display) in Python

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, 3d, polygon

Since I am not certain Python is even a reasonable choice for my goals, let alone which method within Python to select, a bit of background: I am looking to clean up very damaged game polygonal models for 3D printing, so must handle modeling errors and also eliminate hidden surfaces, producing well-formed, solid objects. To that end, I wish to employ a very direct (i.e. brute force for robustness) voxel conversion approach, using my GPU to check visibility by rendering the model's polygons from each voxel's perspective (camera centered at voxel, then multiple angles). If the initial background color is still in the rendered image after the model is drawn in a different color, it must be visible from outside the model and is therefore empty space.

So, what is the best way to approach this task in Python? Is Python even capable of it with a reasonable degree of performance? Only one model, so polygon count is low, but many voxels to be determined as they must be created at a fine resolution. Tried Googling, but what I found seemed geared towards displaying to the screen. Thanks very much.

Comment: It depends if you are using some library for cleaning your mesh and that library is in python then you can use Python OpenGL binding to just draw and see the result.
https://stackabuse.com/brief-introduction-to-opengl-in-python-with-pyopengl/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough: I am writing my own model cleanup program, not using an existing library. What I am looking for assistance on is using OpenGL to draw images to a quickly read memory buffer, rather than directly to the display, as part of that algorithm. Given the highly optimized nature of GPUs, this may not even be possible. I gave an overview of the method I plan to use which was probably too much detail and confused things. I apologize.